# What is context in PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences used for?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

Given that any non-null context passed to PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences will return the same result,
what is context used for by PreferenceManager and what's the point of passing in different context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is context used for by PreferenceManager

To get at the locations of internal storage and, IIRC, the package name of the app.

> what's the point of passing in different context?

In general, any `Context` will do for this method call. In principle, you could pass in some `ContextWrapper` that overrides something that would be used by `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: Why do different activity contexts return the same internal location?

Comment: @Boon: Because internal storage is per app, not per activity.